Is there any difference between set some_option=something and &some_option = something?
I may be wrong, but it feels like that set some_option = ... is a sort of old way for setting options, whereas &some_option = ... seems newer and it appears more powerful. In-fact, the latter allows you to do something like the following:
var something
&option = something .. " something else"

Am I missing something?

Yes, one is the traditional approach, that is compatible to old original vi, the other is using evaluation of VimScript method, that is generally the saner approach when scripting.

Thanks for the answer! A small feedback: I personally found a bit confusing discerning if something is in Vim for legacy reasons or because it is something that we actually need, like for example  and ... Perhaps something to highlight better in the docs? :)

Well, everything in Vim is there because at some time someone found a need for it  :)

You can do either of the following:
set option=value
let &option = value

and, in vim9script:
&option = value

:help :set has been there forever because it was part of ex and vi, while :help :let is a pure "vimism" that appeared when scripting was added to Vim around version 5.0.
:set inherits the limitations of most other Ex command, the main one being that, when used to set an option, it only takes a string as argument (yes, even 123) for that option.
When scripting was added, it became possible—and more elegant—to use :let:
:let &option = something .. "," something_else

and, now that vim9script made :let redundant, you can do:
vim9script
&option = something .. "," something_else

So yes, :set is indeed limiting in a serious scripting context, where you might want to build the value programmatically, but it still perfectly fine in all other contexts where those limitations don't matter: command-line, ftplugins, etc.
In short, the decision to use either of those methods depends on the context.

About Ex commands: in-fact exe is another life-safer when scripting.
